# Obligation to connect solar panels on one's rooftop to the grid in Italy?

Tags: italy

A friend wants to install solar panels (less than 10 kW peak) on her rooftop in Italy for self-consumption. She does not want to feed any solar power into the grid although her house is also connected to the grid. Technically, this can be very simply solved, but the local company told her that she might have an obligation to connect her solar panels to the grid.

I know more or less the regulations in Germany, Austria and Switzerland, and there to my understanding such a grid connection is not obligatory if the solar power is **purely** self-consumed. I did not find anything on the Internet with regard to Italy, but I am skeptical that it is true what the local company told her.

Does anybody have information on this or could point me to according regulations?

Comment: For curiousity: Why would one want to avoid backfeeding into the grid? The alternative is to "burn" the excess electricity somehow, which is just a waste of free resources, particularly because you get some money from feeding into the grid.

Comment: There is enough electrical load available, so there will be no excess energy. Basically she wants to avoid paperwork which comes with a grid connection of the solar panels.

Comment: How is she going to control whether the load is powered by the solar system or the grid? Or is she going to have the solar circuit completely isolated from the grid circuit, i.e. some load will be powered by solar _only_?

Comment: She would operate the loads (like pumps in the garden) via solar, and there would be a manual switch to connect the pumps to the grid in case of days with no sun. I am aware that one can  optimize this, but this is basically the idea.

Comment: Regardless of the laws and regulations, an inverter capable of working in island mode can easily be significantly more expensive than a standard grid-tied inverter, negating any savings on paperwork.